# Посоветуйте статью или книжку по декодированию mp3

Tags: книги

Пытаюсь разобраться с декодированием mp3 искал информацию в интернете не нашёл ни одной полной статьи на эту тему, может я плохо искал. Посоветуйте статью или книжку по этому делу желательно на русском.

Comment: стандарт музыки mp3 имел большую проблему с патентом. Нужно было платить большие отчисления для использования mp3. Почти все патенты уже истёкли по сроку. Но память осталась. Поищите. Помочь не могу, пользуюсь **OGG**.

Comment: @AlexGlebe спасибо за информацию, Сам в шоке один из самых используемых форматов а информации мало.

Answer (score 1):

Много материала на сайте http://www.mp3-tech.org/, в том числе разные Technical papers по теме mp3.

Блок схемы и математические модели и примеры реализаций там тоже есть.

http://lame.sourceforge.net/index.php - крутой опенсорсный кодер начала века.